# Selection Dependent Dropdowns - One is Selectable By Case

Tags: combobox

We have three fields:

- One is a selection for Types, let's define it as C
- The second one is dependent on C, let's define it as N
- The third one could be selectable by case, meaning it is not displayed for every user, only for the specific ones. Let's define it as S. The importance of S is that it defines the Types, I mean that C is dependent on the selection of S.
- And finally, this is a create page, and the focus is C since we create a definition based on the selection for C.

The question is how should we place these inputs?
The current one is this, but I do not like it since once an eligible user selects a type from Field-S, we make the selection on C empty because this selection is not applicable based on the selection on S.
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackExchange UX! This looks like a good forms question, but can you explain why if C is dependent on the selection of S, you have S at the *bottom* of your form here? That doesn't appear to make sense unless I've misunderstood you. It would lead to an obvious loop.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply.

This is the current version of the form, and I asked for how to make better of it?
For now, the idea of this placement is that the user should focus on C since it will be the main item of this creation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you will come into this Create page already knowing some information about S, because you said that it is not displayed for every user but for some users only. This means that the information relating to whether or not S needs to be displayed needs to be determined already.

Then you said that N is dependent on C, and C is dependent on the selection of S. That means the hierarchy or dependency goes in the order of:

- Selection of value for field S to produce values for field C
- Selection of value for field C to produce values for field N
- Selection of value for field N

That's the order I would display the fields, while recognizing that field S might not be shown for every user.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some detail to Michael's answer...

(1) For the users who don't see S, the C field (or its selection list) is prepopulated by the data derived from the implicit selection of S.

(2) There is an issue with such dependencies when the user needs to change a field (e.g., C) determining legal values of another field (e.g., N), after this other field (e.g., N) has been filled in: How does the system tell the user to select again (in case the first choice in N became illegal), or that there are different legal values now (and the user might want to change her first legal choice in N to another, newly legal choice). What you can do here depends on the actual visuals of the form and the consequences of a wrong choice:

- The easy case is to simply remove illegal values and let the user check the form again.
- The system could flag fields with a now illegal value, prompting the user to inspect this field.
- If there are severe consequences, the system could also show a dialog saying "dependent fields have changed; check them again". That's disruptive, so only to be used in rare cases.